# Retrieving remaining quota for Google Services in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script

I haven't found any offical information about my issue anywhere which is why I'm asking.

I found the daily quotas for Google services here:
[Google Service quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

What I haven't found is a function or dashboard where I can see the remaining calls I have for these services.
The only thing I found was the following function for MailApp:

```
MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
```

Is there any possibility to get something similar for GmailApp or even Maps.Geocoder ?

Comment: Update: Called Google Support for clarification. Feature is going to be added in the future.